# Code splitting causes css chunks to be outdated resulting in google Indexed cached pages being raw HTML

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, caching, prerender

Been looking for a solution for this issue quite a while. Quick intro: Our build is ReactJS for frontend. We use Prerender.io to cache pages prior to indexing bots requesting the cached url. Cloudflare is our CDN.

Our pages are indexed properly by google as can be seen here:

[image: Google Results]

But when clicking on the indexed result we get something like this:

[image: Google Indexed Result]

I'm pretty sure at this point that the root issue is that we use code-splitting where possible, and on every deploy with Heroku the chunk names change (we deploy new versions at least 1-2x a week). That means that `prerender.io` still serves old versions to indexing bots like googlebot with outdated css chunks, resulting in a raw version of the page being displayed as the indexed pathnames for css files don't exist anymore.

Does anyone have a solution, or idea for a solution to this issue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same exact issue, also using ReactJS and Cloudflare. I was able to resolve this by going into my Cloudflare speed settings, and then optimization where I had to turn OFF the Brotli compression option (under content optimization) and 0-RTT Connection Resumption (Under protocol optimization). Then I deleted the cached pages under the prerender.io cache manager and tested again with Google's webmaster live tool where everything went back to normal.

Comment: Np, one note, every time you make a new build to your website you'll still have  to re-cache all of your pre-render pages or it will cause the problem again since the old cache will not have the new CSS path. (I noticed that after my solution, so maybe it's possible to turn those two back on if you always re-cache after a new build, but I haven't bothered.)

Comment: Ok got it. Do you know if there is a way to keep css paths static for files that haven't been changed when deplyoying?

For example if i change a product page, or something on the backend, i could keep other pages with the previous bundles & css paths since nothing has changed.